# How to make word wrap on text field in scroll pane work properly and not trigger horizontal scroll

Tags: actionscript-3, word-wrap, scrollpane

I have a textfield ("noteText") inside a container movieclip ("noteContainer"), and I'm setting a scrollpane's source to

```
scrollPane.source = noteContainer;
```

It all works well, however word wrap is doing this:

[image]

ie it's triggering the horizontal scrolling. I want it to wrap where it should and not trigger the horizontal scroller.

I could make noteText's width smaller, but I want to keep it the same width as noteContainer to make the most of screen real estate.

How do I get the wrap to take into account the width of the vertical scrollbar please?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because I hadn't set the autoSize property of "noteText" - once set toe "left", it fixed it.